PyScript OpenCV -- Blank Screen
I am attempting to load an opencv-python functionality to HTML using pyscript, but I am only getting blank browser screen after the messages - "Loading Runtime ... Runtime Created ... Initializing Components", as attached in the screenshot
Please find the python code and html for your review, Can you please let me know, if anything is wrong.


import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import inotify.adapters
import glob
import time
from pathlib import Path
from rembg import remove, new_session
import glob
from pyscript import display


session = new_session()
edgeTotal = 0.0
for file in Path('/home/kali/Desktop/TVS/REMBG/').glob('*.png'):
    input_path = str(file)
    #output_path = str('/home/kali/Downloads/REMBG/' + (file.stem + ".out.png"))

    with open(input_path, 'rb') as i:
        input = i.read()
        #print(input)
        input_img = cv2.imread(input_path)
        #img = cv2.resize(input_img, (500, 500))
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Blur the image for better edge detection
        img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 0)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
        edgedRes = 0
        #edgeTotal = 0.0
        edgedRes = np.sum(edged)

        edgeTotal += edgedRes
        print("summa")
        print(edgeTotal)
        display(edgeTotal, target="mpl")
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
        <!-- Recommended meta tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
   <title>TVS</title>
    <py-env>
            - numpy
            - opencv-python
      </py-env>
<py-config>
  - autoclose_loader: true
  - runtimes:
    - src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/dev/full/pyodide.js"
      name: pyodide-dev
      lang: python
</py-config>

</head>

<body>
    <section class="pyscript">
            
            <div id="mpl"></div>
             <py-script src="./r2.py" output="debug"></py-script>
        </section>
</body>
</html>




Thanks
Guru
